# How to echo the post's content

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables like this:

*posts* table:

```
post_id    subject    
   1         abc
   2         def
```

and *contents* table, of which the `post_id` column is the foreign key:

```
content_id    post_id     content              date
     1           1        main content       2014-07-31 03:02:00
     2           1        reply one          2014-07-31 03:03:20
     3           1        reply two          2014-07-31 03:06:32
```

As you can see, the *contents* table stores both the post's content and its possible repli(es). Here, in this example, the `post_id` # 1 has its main content and two replies.

What I want to do is to **echo** the subject and its content only, **but not the replies**. So I have coded the query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT subject, content
          FROM posts As p
          INNER JOIN contents AS c USING (post_id)
          ORDER BY post_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "{$row['content']}n\";
}
```

Then you know what?. It echoes out the latest content of the post, which is the `content_id` # 3. However, what I wanted to do is to echo the post's content, which is the oldest `content_id` of the `post_id` # 1.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: how are you distinguishing `content` from `replies` in *contents* table?

Comment: @NoobEditor: Amy `content_id` that appears in the *contents* table first is the post's content. Other possible `content_id(s)` associated with the `post_id` afterward is(are) its repli(es).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

It basically selects the minimum date per post in a subquery and uses it as a key for the "normal" query to look for.

```
SELECT distinct subject, content FROM content c
JOIN post p 
on c.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE cast(c.post_id as char)+cast(c.contentdate as char)in               
        (
        SELECT 
        cast(p.post_id as char)+cast(min(c.contentdate) as char) as KeyValue
        FROM post p
        INNER JOIN content c on p.post_id = c.post_id
        GROUP BY p.post_id
        )
```

This returns me:

```
subject | content
----------------------
asd     | main content
def     | main content
```

Comment: I am very new to use `cast` in `WHERE` clause. So, I want to look at the `Fiddle` hyperlink to see the outputs before testing it. However, the hyperlink has died. Can you refresh it, please? or give some more detailed explanation how it works in `WHERE` clause please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eric_ph I think sqlfiddle.com is having some issues at the moment, so I guess you will be able to see it later on. I'll try to explain in this comment: What this query does is to try and compare a concatenated value (something like 131 Jul 2014 03:02:00 which is built up from the ID and the lowest date) from the content table with a subquery, that returns only the minimum dates (so the inital postings) of the entries by Id. To sum it up: It will take the earliest date per ID from each different post, and will pass this value to the main query that will retreive all the relevant data.

Comment: Is it the first `cast(post_id)` in `WHERE` clause exactly the `cast(p.post_id)` or `cast(c.post_id)`? Is the `contentdate` the `date` column in the *contents* table? How should I echo out? is it `$row['content']`? and what is the **KeyValue** for? *Sorry but I am so confused in front of this complicated query!* I have tested it and it returned the error like this: `MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar) + cast(contentdate AS varchar) in (SELECT c' at line 3`. help. Thank

Comment: @Eric_ph I have updated the answer, can you please take a look?

Comment: It **works** now. However, it respectively and **repeatedly** echoes the contents along with the subject ID**s**. I mean if the subject has more than 1 `content_id` in the *contents* table, it returns the pairs of subject-content repeatedly from `oldest to newest` (your `min()` function works for this, i guessed) unless i add the `GROUP (c.post_id)` function into the query. Then I added the `GROUP(c.post_id) after `WHERE` clause, it then **returned** ONLY the *newest* content-subject in accordance with the order of the date column (of course, the newest). Reminder: echo"{$row['subject']}\n";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60171/discussion-between-alex-and-eric-ph).

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the possible usage/functionality of the `KeyValue`, please? because I do not have much knowledge about where it is used in the query. Maybe, other users need to know it too. Thanks

Comment: KeyValue is just a name of the concatenation that takes the ID and the Date's String equivalents to serve as a list the main query can select the results from.

Answer (score 1):

`MIN(DATE)` has to be content, so you need to GROUP the `id` with the `DATE`

Join  both tables on the basis of `post_id` and then group on the basis of `min(date)`

```
$query = "SELECT p.post_id,  p.subject, c.content, c.date
          FROM posts p
          INNER JOIN contents c on p.post_id = c.post_id
          WHERE date = (select min(date) 
                        from contents ct 
                        where ct.post_id = p.post_id 
                        )
          GROUP BY post_id,subject,content, date
          ORDER BY post_id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "{$row['content']}n\";
}
```

Comment: Your query is good. However, as the `post_id` #1 has got 1 content and 2 replies (total = 3 `content_id`s, it echoes out three subjects repeatedly along with its replies. So, how can we have `subject and content` echo'ed only once, **but not** `the replies`? Thanks

Comment: it's ok. However, it echoes out only one subject in the table. You can imagine that the *posts* table might have ` *n* ` posts. So, `LIMIT 0,1` does not work as I just tested.

Comment: Already tried `LIMIT 1` too. But it returned only the latest subject in the `posts` table.

Comment: @Eric_ph : i really feel like Noob now...updated query..please check if this time it works! :)

Comment: YOURS **works** now. However, I have to make it clearer in the answer below

Comment: Another arising difficulty *(i'm not sure if it's the cons or not)* about this query is that I found it difficult (**actually failed**) to apply the `COUNT(content_id) - 1 AS numberOfReplies` to count the number of repli(es) it might have. `echo "{$row['numberOfReplies']}\n";`. @Alex's answer can solve this very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order results by content_id (or date) too. So the sql query might look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT subject, content
      FROM posts As p
      INNER JOIN contents AS c USING (post_id)
      ORDER BY post_id DESC, content_id ASC";
```

And, of course, I assume that the main content has added to database before the replies and you will not alter the row indexes which might lead to situation where the first row with certain post_id isn't the actual content.

So, if you want to print out everything you need to do something in your code. You need to print only the first ones of rows with same post_id:

```
$last_post_id = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($last_post_id != $row['post_id']) {
        echo "{$row['content']}n\";
    }
    $last_post_id = $row['post_id'];
}
```

Comment: Your query is pretty much the same as @`NoobEditor`, which is good. Can you have a look at my comment on his answer, please?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should try adding `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query. Then you get only the content, not replies.

Comment: if I added `LIMIT 1` to the query, I got only the latest subject and , yes, along with its main content, **not replies**. You are right! However, the *posts* table might have `n` subjects in it. So the other ones were not printed out as I wished. That's the reason why I used `\n` in the `echo"....";`.

Comment: Your `if` conditional also failed as I just tested. I also tried changing `$last_post_id = 0` to `$last_post_id = array()`, but no success either!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT subject, content
          FROM posts As p
          INNER JOIN contents AS c USING (post_id)
          ORDER BY date ASC, post_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing all the answers here, I chose the answer of *@NoobEditor*. However, I have to make it clearer as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT p.post_id,  p.subject, c.content, c.date
          FROM posts p
          INNER JOIN contents c on p.post_id = c.post_id
          WHERE date = (select min(date) 
                        from contents c 
                        where c.post_id = p.post_id 
                       )
         GROUP BY c.post_id
         ORDER BY p.post_id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)
```

In which I made it clearer at the `GROUP` and `ORDER BY` functions. And use **c** as alias for *contents* table, but not need to use *c* and *ct*

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo "{$row['content']}n\";
}
```